# Bass and Treble-Car Steroes

Tags: energy, waves, acoustics, diffraction

In a car which phenomenon, diffraction or the resonant frequency of the car, lends itself more to the ability of bass to go farther?

Related Answer: [Why do bass tones travel through walls?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/18090/why-do-bass-tones-travel-through-walls)

Comment: Neither?  The sound energy falls with the square of the distance so unless the car focuses the sound in a particular direction it'll only go as far as the the energy of the sound allows.

Comment: Is the sound supposed to be heard inside or outside the car?